# Text is not written at top in div but little over middle

Tags: html, css

I want to make the Nvidia Hardware a headline in the center at the top of the div, and same css in the right box, but instead of it saying Nvidia hardware it shall be AMD Hardware. My problem is that the headline is written at a very weird place just a little bit over the center.

https://jsfiddle.net/royeeLsq/ -------- (Stretch out the result box so the two boxes is aligned with the div saying Windows)

```css
    .windowsbar {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .windows1, .windows2 {
    background: white;
     display: inline-flex;
    width: 49.7%;
    height: 200px;
    
    }

    .windows1 h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="windowsbar">
    <h1>Windows Software</h1>
    
    <div class="windows1">
    <h1>nvidia hardware</h1>
        </div>
        
    <div class="windows2">
        <p>test</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: @G-Cyr I'm not sure what you mean. (I am not that experienced with html,css..)

Comment: Nono, the fiddle is what my problem looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.windowsbar {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
 }

 .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.window {
    flex: 40%; /* Important */
    background: white;
    margin: 1em;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: center; 
}

.window h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="windowsbar">
    <div>
      <h1>Windows Software</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="window">
        <h1>nvidia hardware</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="window">
        <h1>amd</h1>
      </div>    
            <div class="window">
        <h1>intel hardware</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="window">
        <h1>Qualcomm</h1>
      </div>  
    </div>         
</div>
```

Comment: This is really close to what I was looking for, so i'm going to use this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the line-height property for your h1 tag to 20px and remove display: inline-flex from window container. It should work then. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

check my forked version of your fiddle
1- no need to use different classes for the same style `windows1, windows2` you can use single class for both
2- table approach may be more reliable for your target just add a parent to you boxes and width `display:table` you can achieve your goal

https://jsfiddle.net/royeeLsq/3/

```css
body{
  background:#333;
}
.windowsbar {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px auto;
    line-height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
}

.windows {
    background: white;
     
    
    height: 200px;
    text-align:center;
}
.table{
  display:table;
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.table-cell{
  padding:0 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  width:50%;
}
.windows h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="windowsbar">
    <h1>Windows Software</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="table">
      
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="windows">
      <h1>nvidia hardware</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
     <div class="windows">
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```